# Node writestream brakes when it run for the second time

Tags: javascript, node.js, backend

```
var download =  function(uri, filename, callback){
    console.log("inside download function");
    request.head(uri, function(err, res, body){
      request(uri).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(filename)).on('close', callback);
    });
    console.log("downloaded image")
};
```

This code is supposed to download a picture and save it , works once and brakes the second time giving me a unknown error

This code brakes the second time i run it , and if i restart it , it works for once and brake again giving me this error

```
node:events:492
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: UNKNOWN: unknown error, open 'C:\Users\7A7z\Documents\zumi image processing\cashe\234pfp.png'
Emitted 'error' event on WriteStream instance at:
    at WriteStream.onerror (node:internal/streams/legacy:62:12)
    at WriteStream.emit (node:events:514:28)
    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
  errno: -4094,
  code: 'UNKNOWN',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: 'C:\\Users\\7A7z\\Documents\\zumi image processing\\cashe\\234pfp.png'
}
```

Comment: Why are you using a head request beforehand?